# How can Jdbc template be used for UPDATE query with IN clause?

Tags: sql, spring, templates, jdbc, in-clause

I've gone through various forums to handle the IN clause using spring's namedParamJdbcTemplate but i still do not get the stuff I'm exactly looking for.
Below is my issue:

I've the following method:

```
public void  updateBatchTableForStatus(List<Integer> reportShellIds, String scheduleType) {

    Map<String,List<Integer>> shellIds = Collections.singletonMap("reportShellIds", reportShellIds);
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("reportShellIds", shellIds, Types.NUMERIC)
    parameters.addValue("eventType", scheduleType, Types.VARCHAR);

    this.namedParamJdbcTemplate.update(GET_EVENT_METADATA_INFO, parameters);

}
```

The query refered in above method is as defined below:

```
 public static final String SQL_UPDATE_BATCH_LOOKUP_TABLE_FOR_STATUS_BY_BATCH_IDS = "" +
            "UPDATE " +
            TABLE_BATCH_REF + " BLK " +
            "SET " +
            "BLK.EXECUTION_STATUS_CODE = :eventType " +
            "WHERE " +
            "BLK.BATCH_ID  in(:reportShellIds) ";
```

Datatype for BATCH_ID column is Number(24,0) and for the EXECUTION_STATUS_CODE column Varchar.
I'm using Oracle db.

However, the above method throws a SQL exception.

Can someone pls tell me where I'm wrong and what is the fix for it ?

Many thanks in advance.

Best Regards
LB

Comment: In the future please include the actual SQL exception in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `reportShellIds` to a Map, but it needs to be a List for Spring to bind it correctly. Perhaps you meant `shellIds.values()` or the variable `reportShellIds`?

Comment: I tried using shellIds.values(). I still get SQL exception as before:  org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [<<my sql query>>]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17132]; Invalid conversion requested; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested

Comment: You're not passing a null value by any chance are you? Also, maybe it doesn't like that `.values()` returns a Set rather than a List

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method with simple `Map<String,Object>` and place the array as is into the parameter map

```
 public int update(String sql, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> paramMap)
```